# Is hilly town idiomatic?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

What do you call a town on top of a hill and/or surrounded by hills, is it  hilly town? Could it be ridgy town or mountain town?
I mean a cold town on top of a hill.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a "cold" town? Do you mean that since the town is high in the mountains, it has a cold climate?

Comment: Yes, a cold climate especially at night.

Comment: A chilly hilltop town.

Comment: @user3169 Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a place:

> A chilly hilltop town

I doubt many people would use "hilly town", rather a town with hilly terrain. The *hilly* part refers to the land the town is on, not the town itself.